# Extracting array data from $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, merge

I have two MYSQL tables 'Piece' and 'Order1'

in PHP I would like to loop through each Order (& the pieces within) in this $_POST array and store it in my database.

I've tried to do a while loop, to store each individual order but have been unable to get the pieces underneath each order. I'm thinking maybe this is not the way to go.

If someone to give me an example or suggestion it would be great.

```
    [order] => Array
            (
                [details] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [order1_itemcode] => 
                                [order1_description] => 
                                [order1_itemprice] => 
                                [order1_packagetype] => 0
                                [pieces] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [piece_length] => 235
                                                [piece_width] => 235
                                                [piece_height] => 235
                                                [piece_unittype] => cm
                                                [piece_actualweight] => 
                                                [piece_weighttype] => kg
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [piece_length] => 346
                                                [piece_width] => 346
                                                [piece_height] => 346
                                                [piece_unittype] => cm
                                                [piece_actualweight] => 
                                                [piece_weighttype] => kg
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [order1_itemcode] => 
                                [order1_description] => 
                                [order1_itemprice] => 
                                [order1_packagetype] => 0
                                [pieces] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [piece_length] => 46
                                                [piece_width] => 346
                                                [piece_height] => 346
                                                [piece_unittype] => cm
                                                [piece_actualweight] => 
                                                [piece_weighttype] => kg
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [piece_length] => 346
                                                [piece_width] => 223
                                                [piece_height] => 235
                                                [piece_unittype] => cm
                                                [piece_actualweight] => 
                                                [piece_weighttype] => kg
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
   foreach ($_POST['order']['details'] as $detail)
   {
       foreach($detail['pieces'] as $pieces)
       {
          //store($pieces['piece_length']);
          //store($pieces['piece_width']);
          //store($pieces['piece_height']);
          //store($pieces['piece_unittype']);
          //store($pieces['piece_actualweight']);
          //store($pieces['piece_weighttype']);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, should $orders = $_POST['order']?

Comment: Yes if you are using method post. I have edited the above code, try it again.

Comment: I am just receiving a blank page. But the $_POST['order'] is definitely being posted.

Comment: Did you tried displaying the results using print_r or var_dump? Like this var_dump($pieces);

Comment: Yes, just did another tested and it returned: Array ( [details] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [order1_itemcode] => [order1_description] => [order1_itemprice] => [order1_packagetype] => 0 [pieces] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [piece_length] => 235 [piece_width] => 235 [piece_height] => 235 [piece_unittype] => cm [piece_actualweight] => [piece_weighttype] => kg ) ) ) ) )

Comment: This allowed me to do what I need to, thank you very much. I spent hours trying to work this out. I'm certain i had over complicated in every possible way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [array_walk_recursive()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function

Comment: This function provides you with custom control on what you do with elements you are going over in an array, whereas a foreach loop just goes over all the elements.

Comment: Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function.

Comment: I believe that's only with array_walk

Answer (score 0):

it will be better to use

```
 foreach($_POST['order']['details'] as $key=>$order)
 {
    if(is_array($order['pieces']) && $key=='pieces')
    {
      foreach($order['pieces']) as $pices)
      $insert[]=implode(',',$pices);//array for later insert,you should do necessary validation and should deal with mysql injection
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just updated my original question to include the names of the arrays. I haven't been able to get what im after yet? Care to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($orders as $order)
{
   //store($order)

   $pieces = $order['pieces'];
   foreach($pieces as $a_pieces)
   {
      //store($a_pieces);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, gave it a try but i think ive got my logic wrong.. Check my question again as I have updated the Array to give you more information as to what my arrays are called.